# I am failing to get 'required_changes' with python-apt

Tags: python, apt

```
import sys
from apt.debfile import DebPackage
deb = DebPackage(sys.argv[1])
print(deb.required_changes)
```

I expected the above code to display packages that are supposed to satisfy a dependency of a given deb file, but instead I get a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) of empty [lists](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list):

```
([], [], [])
```

I made sure to check on a package that I know for sure has uninstalled dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to call `deb.check()` to provoke it into returning values for `dep.required_changes`, etc. Also had to pass it an instance of `apt.cache.Cache` else it complained:

```
import sys
from apt.cache import Cache
from apt.debfile import DebPackage

cache = Cache()
deb = DebPackage(sys.argv[1], cache)
deb.check()
print(deb.missing_deps)
print(deb.required_changes)
```

Output:

```
% python apt_info.py ./libzeroc-ice33_3.3.1-12_amd64.deb
['libiceutil33']
(['libiceutil33'], [], [])
```

Comment: How did you figure that out? Did you look at the source code? It is so not obvious.

Comment: Are you sure about the `apt.cache` part? I am using `0.7.100` (version in Debian 6), and the above code without it.

Comment: The `apt.cache` part may only be necessary on Ubuntu (I'm running Lucid, `0.7.94`). I did take a peek at the source briefly, noticing that `deb.check()` called `deb._satisfy_depends()` under the hood, which in turn marked packages for install in the cache. That ensured that `deb.required_changes` returned results.

Comment: Yeah you are right. In some later python-apt versions, if you leave out the cache argument, `apt.cache.Cache()` is called automatically.